# Weird font artifacts

Tags: vim

I often encounter artifacts like these:

[image]

I have to simply redraw the screen to remove them, but I was wondering if it's possible to completely get rid of them. I've tried [Seth Messer's trick](https://coderwall.com/p/tnopnw), but it doesn't work.

I use gvim 7.4.0-2 on Arch Linux with nvidia 325.15-3.

Comment: Which platform? I think this has more to do with the OS/graphics library than vim itself.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot to add any information.

Comment: have you tried to change your font ?

Comment: @Vdt I experience them even after changing the font to DejaVu Sans Mono.

Comment: My best bet is this is the problem of graphic card driver. It's not vim's problem.

Comment: That fix is for another problem, no wonder it doesn't work.